# How to select multiple rows in a UI grid without holding CTRL key using C#?

Tags: c#, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a table written in Angular and when I write the code below, I can't click to select multiple rows (it works for the table example below). For my table at work, it only allows me to select one row at a time so looping is not working.
My question is how to select all rows in a UI grid table?

I've tried writing a loop to click until the last row is reached, but for the Angular site at work, it only allows one row to be selected at a time. I can't use the CTRL key as it needs to run without user interaction. I've looked into the Actions class for selenium but I can't get it to work.

```
class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWebElement tableElement;

        String _address = "https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_row.html";

            IWebDriver _driver = new ChromeDriver();

            _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(_address);
            tableElement = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("example"));

        Actions actions = new Actions(_driver);

        var noRows = _driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//table[@id='example']/tbody/tr"));

        for (int i = 0; i < noRows.Count; i++)
        {
            noRows[i].Click();
        }

        Console.Write("ALl lines seleected");
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you share the tr html (one for selected and not selected)

Comment: This is one row of the table HTML  <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Position</th>
       <th>Office</th>
       <th>Age</th>
       <th>Start date</th>
       <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
       <td>System Architect</td>
       <td>Edinburgh</td>
       <td>61</td>
       <td>2011/04/25</td>
       <td>$320,800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out by adding this line

actions.KeyDown(Keys.Control).Click(gridTotal[1]).KeyUp(Keys.Control).Build().Perform();